# Eager loading laravel 3 deep relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I got a model City related with State and so with Country.

When call a model realted with city a got the city but state return null.

my query

```
Agent::with(array('city','city.state'))->find($id);
```

my model city

```
class City extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'city';

    public function State()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('State','state_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is `State` but you reference `city.state`. Don't know if that would have any affect on it but try making the method `state` (lowercase).

Comment: do not affects at all make the same affects lower and upper case.

Answer (score 1):

Using an enclosure method should work...

```
// Like this...
Agent::with(array('city' => function($query){
    $query->with('state'); 
}))->find($id);

// Also, I would keep my model relationship methods lowercase
class City extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'city';

    //public function State()
    public function state() // like this
    {
         return $this->belongs_to('State','state_id');
    }
}
```

Scroll down to "Constraining Eager Loads" at the below link to see enclosure methods in use
https://tower.la.utexas.edu/index.php/docs/database/eloquent#eager